# Magic variable for entire command, including &&

Tags: bash

I'm trying to write a little function for bash like so:

```
alias timesec='/usr/bin/time --format="%C took %e seconds"'

prun() {
    echo \$ $@
    timesec $*
}
```

But when I use it, I get:

```
mpen@mpen:/topsecret$ prun echo foo && echo bar
$ echo foo
foo
echo foo took 0.00 seconds
bar
```

I want that first line to say `$ echo foo && echo bar` and the `timesec` should also apply to the entirety of the command (`echo foo && echo bar`) not just the first half.

How would I do this?

Comment: No way. That's the reason why the `time` reserved word exists in bash.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `TIMEFORMAT` variable to customize the output of bash's `time` builtin:

```
 cmd="/bin/echo foo && /bin/echo bar"
 # See man bash for the TIMEFORMAT variable
 PREV_TIMEFORMAT="${TIMEFORMAT}"
 TIMEFORMAT="The command ${cmd} took %lR"
 # You could use time eval "${cmd}". I don't recommend that
 time /bin/echo foo && /bin/echo bar
```

Output:

```
foo
bar
The command /bin/echo foo && /bin/echo bar took 0m0.00s
```

Note: The above "solution" doesn't work when you use bash's `echo` builtin.

Comment: How does this solution work with variables though? That's the part I'm having trouble with.